# Loading content into iFrame

Tags: html, iframe

I have a html page that uses an iFrame to switch between different profiles in a gallery.
Everything works fine, but I would also like to change the default profile that is loaded depending on which link the user uses to get to the page.

```
<div class="profile_container">
<iframe src="profiles/user01.html" width="900" height="440" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="figher_profile"></iframe>
</div>
```

So, in short, I need to be able to specify which "user" is loaded into the iFrame.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have the script that handles the iframe?

Comment: No, I have just placed the iframe using the code above.